# C++ Wait For Mutex

Tags: c++, mutex

I have a C# app that creates a mutex:

```
 var mutex = new Mutex(true, // desire initial ownership
           "MyMutexName",
           out owned);
```

How would an unmanaged C++ app detect when this mutex is released?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684315(VS.85).aspx), then [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032(VS.85).aspx)